# Regex capture group returning wrong value

Tags: python, regex-group

From a script that underscores suburbs in address lists. All suburbs must be underscored. However when there is a street with the same name as the suburb these have been underscored too which is not wanted. The lines of code shown are used to correct this situation. They have been copied from the script.

This is a small sample of what is contained within a larger data sample. The address lists being processed are from text files. Here is a small chunk where Howard Road has been underscored in error.

```
import re

addressList = ['118 Nile Street _Lower_Hutt Widow','88 _Howard Road _Point_Howard Student','168 Wellington Road _Wainuiomata Driver']
pattern1 = r'(\d?\/?)(\d+[A-z]?\s)_([A-z]\S+)(?=\s)(\s.+)|(\d+[A-z]?)(\d+[A-z]?\s)_([A-z]\S+)(?=\s)(\s.+)'

for i in range(len(addressList)):
    replacedLine = addressList[i]
   
    result = re.search(pattern1,replacedLine,flags=0)

    if result:
            print("There was a result!")
            if result.group(1) is None or result.group(1) == '':
                print("There was no group 1")
                replacedLine = re.sub(pattern1, r'\2\3\4', replacedLine)
            else:
                print("All groups present")
                replacedLine = re.sub(pattern1, r'\1\2\3\4', replacedLine)
                       
            print("New replaced line:",replacedLine)
```

The breakdown of the pattern is [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXiLPA/1). This pattern must be able to match various street numbering like: 2/22, 2A. Which is why there is an OR statement included. The logic is to return all capture groups (less the underscore of the street name) If the street number is single digit then return all capture groups other than capture group 1.

This script returns the correct result. The only change to `addressList` is the removal of the street underscore:

```
There was a result!
All groups present
New replaced line: 88 Howard Road _Point_Howard Student
```

The issue is that the results from my files have errors. In all cases the leftmost digit of this example return 1s. So the result shown here would be: `18 Howard Road _Point_Howard Student`

Having carefully checked the output right before the code shown here and after in my full version code. I am sure the problem is here but unfortunately can't reproduce it in this example. This behavior only occurs for underscores being removed from street numbers greater than 9. So single digit addresses remain correct. This means the problem is only occurring in the `All groups present` branch.

Comment: One suggestion: You’re more likely to get a good answer if you showed your regex pattern, input string, and the expected and actual output. We don’t need a long drawn out story here, as that serves no purpose in understanding the question.

Comment: I have done that. No 'long drawn out story' Just some context. Maybe I should have said good ideas appreciated.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're looking for.  But have you looked at regex101.com, which lets you enter a regex and a string, and it shows you all the matches?  That may help.

Comment: If you had followed the link "demo" you would see the regex and see I have already been there many times before. How about please doing a bit more research before firing off a comment that is bound to annoy the person posting.

Comment: Since the error is not reproduced by this section of code, it most likely occurs before it. Could you add data from the source file and what result do you want to get in the end. Perhaps there is another solution.

Comment: Good suggestion. But I have checked output down to the line before. It's good. The debug output shows what's wrong: `result: <re.Match object; span=(0, 37), match='88 _Howard Road _Point_Howard Student'> Rep line: 88 _Howard Road _Point_Howard Student
result: 18 Howard Road _Point_Howard Student`

Comment: This is one of the most baffling things I have come across. I have no idea where the number 1  comes from. I was hoping someone would suggest an alternative to my way of filtering out the underscore. Or a replacement for `re.sub()` Something like that.

Comment: You are trying to fix a bug, but it would be better to fix the previous code so that it doesn't occur at all.

Comment: The previous code produces exactly what is intended. It reads from a 400 line text file. The code itself is around 150 lines. The error pattern is regular and predictable.

Comment: Need a few lines from the file, with the problem and the desired result.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: It's not clear how we're supposed to help with this. You say this script returns the correct result. You need to show us an example where it doesn't return the correct result.

Comment: Any particular reason? I mean I think you should back up your assertion with at least an example. I go for readability first.

Comment: There's no real difference between your `if` and `else` branches. If group 1 is empty, nothing will be substituted for `\1` in the replacement. So the two replacements are effectively the same.

Comment: One big problem I can see is that you don't handle the cases where the second alternative matches. Then capture groups 1 through 4 will all be empty, and you need to use groups 5-8.

Comment: The if branch returns the expected. That is if there is only a single digit address then it returns everything except group 1. For `8 _Nile Street _Lower_Hutt Widow` the output is: `There was a result!
There was no group 1
result: 8 Nile Street _Lower_Hutt Widow`